# Count missing values per class

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking to check the pattern of missing values according to a class label (dependent variable) in my data. The output I want is the class labels and the number of missing values in the class.

```
library(tidyverse)

fakeData <- data.frame(var1 = c(1,2,NA,4,NA,6,7,8,9,10),
                       var2=c(11,NA,NA,14,NA,16,17,NA,19,NA), 
                       Class = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5)))

fakeData %>% group_by(Class) %>% summarize(numMissing = sum(is.na())) 

Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
Evaluation error: 0 arguments passed to 'is.na' which requires 1.
```

What is wrong with my approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a cleaner solution, using tidyverse only. You don't need to know the number of columns. You can also use `?select_helpers` in `gather()` to select columns, eg. `starts_with("var")`.

```
fakeData %>% 
  group_by(Class) %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -Class) %>% # all except Class 
  summarise(missing_n = sum(is.na(value)))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Class  missing_n
  <fctr>     <int>
1 A              5
2 B              2
```

Comment: Very idiomatic tidyverse!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, we can do

```
fakeData %>%
      group_by(Class) %>%
      summarise_all(funs(sum(is.na(.)))) %>%
      transmute(Class, numMissing = var1 + var2)
```

If we have many columns, then use `purrr::reduce`

```
fakeData %>%
    group_by(Class) %>% 
    summarise_all(funs(sum(is.na(.)))) %>% 
    transmute(Class, numMissing = .[-1] %>% reduce(`+`))
    #or with rowSums
    #transmute(Class, numMissing = rowSums(.[-1]))
```

Comment: Works like a charm, but I have 19 columns in my original data. How do I handle that?

Comment: `%>% transmute(Class, numMissing = Reduce("+", .[2:18]))` or `transmute(Class, numMissing = Reduce("+",.[-1]))`

Comment: @buzaku added some alternatives.

Comment: None at all. If i could accept 2 answers I would. It is just a personal preference towards tidy, tidy verse. :)

Comment: @buzaku Thanks, no problem.  I was a bit curious if it went wrong in any of your datasets

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest melting dataset in long format using reshape lib. Then just use aggregate function by Class variable.

```
library(reshape)

fakeData <- data.frame(var1 = c(1,2,NA,4,NA,6,7,8,9,10),
                       var2=c(11,NA,NA,14,NA,16,17,NA,19,NA), 
                       Class = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5)))

fData <- melt(fakeData, measure.vars = c("var1", "var2"))

fData
   Class variable value
1      A     var1     1
2      A     var1     2
3      A     var1    NA
4      A     var1     4
5      A     var1    NA
6      B     var1     6
7      B     var1     7
8      B     var1     8
9      B     var1     9
10     B     var1    10
11     A     var2    11
12     A     var2    NA
13     A     var2    NA
14     A     var2    14
15     A     var2    NA
16     B     var2    16
17     B     var2    17
18     B     var2    NA
19     B     var2    19
20     B     var2    NA

with(fData, aggregate(value, list(Class), function(x) { sum(is.na(x)) }))
  Group.1 x
1       A 5
2       B 2
```

Comment: Same is achieved with `fakeData %>% gather(variable, value, var1:var2)`.